# Does phonegap support Siri?

Tags: cordova, ios5, siri

I just want to know, does phonegap support Siri? If yes, please provide proper guidelines or API.

Thanks,
--regeint

Comment: provide an API? In an answer?

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a Siri API yet - Siri currently only interacts with Apple's apps.